# Why is the ::before in my css not working in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, pseudo-element, next.js13

Here's the React JS file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./body-section.css";
import background from "../etc/Image-robot.jpg";

const Body = () => {
    return (
        <div className="body">
            <div 
                className="bdy-socials-section">
                <img 
                src={background}
                id="bg-img">
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Body;
```

The CSS file:

```
.bdy-socials-section > img {
    width: 55vw;
    height: 80vh;
    transform: SkewY(5deg);
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

.bdy-socials-section > img::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Unfortunately I don't see any visual changes in the Chrome browser

I'm actually at a dead-end :<

Comment: Pseudo-elements don't work on images, unfortunately. Maybe wrap it in a container.

Comment: I did and still not seeing any changes :(

Answer (score 0):

```
// Body.jsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div
        className="bdy-socials-section">
        <div className='img-container'>
          <img
            src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/12825195/pexels-photo-12825195.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1'
            id="bg-img"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
/* Body.css */
.bdy-socials-section {
    width: 70vw;
    transition: all ease 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
}

.bdy-socials-section>.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

.bdy-socials-section>.img-container>img {
    width: 55vw;
    height: 80vh;
    transform: SkewY(5deg);
}

.bdy-socials-section>.img-container::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    transform: SkewY(5deg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}
```